# recovering an overwritten ntfs partition with dd command

Tags: partition, dd, ntfs, testdisk

I accidentally overwrote an NTFS partition with an iso image with the dd command. I am trying to recover NTFS partition with testdisk, but after disk selection (1.8TB), partition table type selection (intel) and analysis, I get the following current partition structure:
[image: partition structure]

At this point I don't know what to do to go on and recover the NTFS partition that I don't see.
Should I choose the HFS line?
Please help me.

Comment: R-Studio Undelete is your best friend and bet.

Answer (score 0):

There pretty much isn't any way to properly fix this. Filesystems hate losing even small parts of themselves, not to mention overwriting hundreds of megabytes with dd.

What I like to do in such a case is determine how much data has been overwritten exactly - either from dd output or by comparing the iso image file with the on disk data (e.g. `cmp datasource /dev/target`). And then zero out the verified-to-be-lost segment.

Example: (use at your own risk - run all experiments on full disk copies or [copy-on-write overlays](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Recovering_a_failed_software_RAID#Making_the_harddisks_read-only_using_an_overlay_file))

```
# cmp isofile.img /dev/diska
cmp: EOF on isofile.img after byte 68157440, in line 266228
# dd bs=1 count=68157440 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diska

# cmp isofile.img /dev/diskb
isofile.img /dev/diskb differ: byte 34603009, line 135095
# head -c $((34603009-1)) /dev/zero > /dev/diskb
```

Zeroing out the damaged area won't recover any of your data. But it will help stop recovery software from making wrong assumptions regarding block sizes and partition offsets, and avoid wasting time recovering data you're not interested in. It's better to have no data at all than completely bogus data that looks valid because it came from a valid image file.

In the future, make backups.

Answer (score -1):

Happened to me once. I used "TestDisk" to recover most of the files (dd was stopped when I recognized the error)
There is an elaborate description [here](https://net2.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-on-linux/) on how to recover lost files

Comment: Please do not post link-only-answers. Also the asker already is aware of testdisk. The information in the provided link do not seem to be related to a situation like in this question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. Will be using links as additional source from now on.